# StackPanes dislocate in GridPane while normal Panes don't. Is this intentional? How can I work around it?

Tags: javafx

I'm essentially trying to represent a chess board using javafx. I have two classes: BoardView which holds 64 instances of TileView in a GridPane. TileView is supposed to visualize the tile background, a chess piece and the file and rank at a later stage. That's why I was going with TileView extends StackPane, so I can just layer those as three different children. For the last like hour I was trying to make the tiles auto resize to occupy all available space for the BoardView.

This is the code I had:

```java
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApplication extends javafx.application.Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new BoardView<>(TileView::new));
        stage.setTitle("MainApplication");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

```java
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;

import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class BoardView<T extends TileView> extends GridPane {
    private TileView[] tiles;

    public BoardView(final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, T> tileFactory) {
        super();

        setPrefSize(640, 640);

        tiles = new TileView[64];
        final ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
        final RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints();
        columnConstraints.setPercentWidth(12.5);
        rowConstraints.setPercentHeight(12.5);
        for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
                final TileView tile = tileFactory.apply(x, y);
                tiles[y * 8 + x] = tile;
                add(tile, x, y);
            }
            getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraints);
            getRowConstraints().add(rowConstraints);
        }

        setGridLinesVisible(true);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```java
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class TileView extends StackPane {
    public final Rectangle background;

    public TileView(final int fileIndex, final int rankIndex) {
        background = new Rectangle();
        background.setFill((fileIndex + rankIndex) % 2 == 0? Color.valueOf("#d18b47") : Color.valueOf("#ffce9e"));
        getChildren().add(background);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(final double newWidth, final double newHeight) {
        super.resize(newWidth, newHeight);
        background.setWidth(newWidth);
        background.setHeight(newHeight);
    }
}
```

This works for the width, but when resizing the height of the window I had this result (The black lines are the grid lines for debuggin purposes):

[image]

After much fumbling around I figured out that StackPanes kinda screw up the positioning and everything is fine if I just let TileView inherit from Pane.

[image]

Now I have the question how can I still use Pane two hold multiple this just layered or if I can fix the bad behaviour while maintaining the original super class StackPane?
If this is a bug (I doubt it, I'm probably just dumb rn), for recreation purposes: I'm using the maven repository OpenJFX » 20-ea+4 and java 20 openjdk;

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try Googling for **javafx chess game** to see how others have done it?

Comment: `ea` is early access software.  Don't use it.  Use non-ea software (latest stable version or latest stable LTS version).

Comment: Why do you override `resize`, especially when you never even call it?  That is kind of strange.  Probably you have some misconceptions about how layout works, though I don't know what they are.

Comment: *"Any help is greatly appreciated"* -> Then please accept the provided popular answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug (not in the JavaFX codebase).

By default, the minimum size of a `StackPane` is calculated by computing the minimum size of its content. Once the rectangles have had their size set (to `80x80` initially), the `StackPane` will not be able to shrink below that size. So if your `GridPane` is made smaller, the individual `StackPane`s within it remain `80x80` and overflow the cells in the grid. By default, the horizontal alignment is on the left of the cell and the vertical alignment is centered. Because the tiles are added top to bottom and left to right, you see the portion of the stack pane that overflows above the cell. (You will not see the overflow below or to the right, because other tiles are drawn on top of that.)

If you add some logging to the `resize(...)` method you'll see it is always called with `80, 80` as parameters. If you add something like `setOnMouseClicked(e -> toFront());` to the constructor of `TileView`, then by clicking on the tiles you can see their full extent:

[image: All tiles are (at least) 80x80 pixels, and may overflow the cell above, below, and to the right]

You can "fix" this by adding

```
    background.setManaged(false);
```

in the `TileView` constructor. This will ensure the background's size is not used in computing the min/pref/max size of the `StackPane`. This way the tiles themselves can be resized to the size of the grid cell.

The caveat here is that you're relying on `resize(double, double)` being called on the tiles every time there is a layout pass, which is really an implementation detail of the container's (`GridPane`) layout code. The underlying problem is that you're trying to implement this by partially doing your own layout (resizing a `Rectangle`). If you really want to go this route, you should probably override `layoutChildren()`, and perhaps other methods.

---

The purpose of the `Rectangle`s is not really clear at all. They just seem to be providing a background color. If that's the case, why not just use the standard API (either `setBackground(...)` or CSS)? For example:

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class TileView extends StackPane {

    public TileView(final int fileIndex, final int rankIndex) {
        Color bgColor = (fileIndex + rankIndex) % 2 == 0? Color.valueOf("#d18b47") : Color.valueOf("#ffce9e");
        setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(bgColor, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
    }

}
```

The CSS version is

```
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class TileView extends StackPane {

    public TileView(final int fileIndex, final int rankIndex) {
        getStyleClass().add("tile");
        PseudoClass odd = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("odd");
        pseudoClassStateChanged(odd, (fileIndex + rankIndex) % 2 == 1);
    }

}
```

with the external style sheet

```
.tile {
    -fx-background-color: #d18b47;
}
.tile:odd {
    -fx-background-color: #ffce9e;
}
```

At this point, the entire `TileView` class may be redundant (you can replace it just with a method creating and returning a `StackPane`), but maybe you have more functionality there in your real application.

Comment: Note: If using JavaFX 18+, then the `setBackground(...)` approach can be simplified to use [`Background#fill(Paint)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Background.html#fill(javafx.scene.paint.Paint)).